How to cut xlxs file into several segments according to the index and create a list with the values ​of each segment
So, I'm analyzing an xlxs file with a few minutes with around 300.000 lines, a large part of which doesn't interest me, it's noise. Using the find_peaks function, I can now filter which time intervals interest me. However, now I needed to give orders to the algorithm to cut the file into segments that correspond to each vehicle passage. In other words, as soon as the first peak of each passage is detected, I need to remove the information 500 points before that peak, and 1000 points after the last peak of that passage.
How can I translate this into code and then create a kind of list or vector where a new algorithm will run to analyze each passage and extract information about it?
Ive tried many different approaches with Chatgpt and with some tips that ive found here in SO but the algorithm was never able to provide the results that I need.
Ill copy the algorithm im using to do the initial filtering of the noise and detection of most important peaks.
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 df = pd.read_excel('2023_09_28_16_59_06.xlsx')

 lag = 500
 influence = 0.5
 threshold = 10


 def find_peak_indices(signal, lag, influence, threshold):
     peak_indices = []  # Lista para armazenar índices de picos
     peaks = []  # Lista para armazenar os valores dos picos
     processed_signal = [] 
     processed_signal.append(signal[:lag])
     avg_list = []
     sd_list = []

     for index in range(lag, len(signal)):
         y = signal[index]
         avg_list.append(np.mean(processed_signal[-lag:]))
         sd_list.append(np.std(processed_signal[-lag:]))

         if abs(y - avg_list[-1]) > sd_list[-1] * threshold:
             peak_indices.append(index)
             peaks.append(signal[index])  # Adiciona o valor do pico encontrado à lista de picos
         if index > 0:
             adjusted_value = (influence * y) + ((1 - influence) * processed_signal[-1])
         else:
             adjusted_value = (influence * y)  # No previous value, take y as is
        
         processed_signal = np.append(processed_signal, [adjusted_value])
         processed_signal = processed_signal[1:]

     return peak_indices, peaks


 signal = df[df.columns[16]]

 peak_indices, peak_values = find_peak_indices(signal, lag, influence, threshold)

 moving_avg = df[df.columns[16]].rolling(window=lag).mean()
 std_dev = df[df.columns[16]].rolling(window=lag).std()

 plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))

 plt.plot(signal, label='Signal')
 plt.plot(moving_avg, color='red', label='Moving Average')
 plt.title('Signal with Moving Average')
 plt.xlabel('Index')
 plt.ylabel('Value')
 plt.legend()
 plt.show()

 plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12)) 

 plt.plot(std_dev, color='green', label='Standard Deviation')
 plt.title('Standard Deviation')
 plt.xlabel('Index')
 plt.ylabel('Value')
 plt.legend()
 plt.show()

 plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))

 plt.plot(signal, label='Signal')
 plt.scatter(peak_indices, peak_values, color='red', label='Peaks')
 plt.title('Signal with Peaks Detected') 
 plt.xlabel('Index')
 plt.ylabel('Value')
 plt.legend()
 plt.show()

 print("Picos encontrados:")
 for i in range(len(peak_indices)):
     print("Índice:", peak_indices[i], "- Valor do pico:", peak_values[i])

I think the approach would have to be something like this:
1- tell the algorithm that I want as soon as the first peak is found, to remove the information from the previous 500 points, and that marks the start of one individual passage.
2-to close each block/passage, or use the instant in which the standard deviation stabilizes for some time or using the first peak found as a reference, define a condition during the next 2 seconds and in that period of time, select the last peak and select 1000 information points from there on. after the 1000 seconds, the passage ends.
I'm currently doing my PhD and my training in civil engineering doesn't give me much resources for this task, so I really appreciate your help.
